# Checkbox checked not working in meteor table

Tags: javascript, meteor, checkbox

been at this for a while now. Basically I have a table, in each table row there is a checkbox. However any input field I place in the rows of the table (this includes those input boxes) I cannot set the default value. So even with the "checked" flag in HTML the boxes remain unchecked....

```
<form id="form" action="#" class="wizard-big">
                        <h1>Requirements</h1>
                        <fieldset>
                            <h2>Set Requirements</h2>


                                <table class="table table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th>COL1 </th>
                                        <th>COL2 </th>
                                        <th>COL3 </th>
                                        <th>COL4 E</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                      {{#each trades}}
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>{{#if DEFAULT}}
                                          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" checked name="check[]">
                                          {{else}}
                                          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" name="check[]">
                                          {{/if}}
                                        </td>
                                          <td>{{PROFILE}}</td>
                                          <td><input type="text" placeholder="{{exposure}}" value="{{exposure}}"></td>
                                          <td style="color:{{prof_expColor}}">{{exposure}}</td>
                                          <td style="color:{{prof_expColor}}">{{exposure}}</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      {{/each}}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                        </fieldset>
```

the relevant JS

```
Template.E4E_collateral.rendered = function(){

// Initialize steps plugin
$("#wizard").steps();

$("#form").steps({
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
  });

$('.i-checks').iCheck({
checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
radioClass: 'iradio_square-green'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not `checked="checked"` it's just `checked`! It's just a boolean attribute, not a string.

See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox)

You can also simplify:

```
<td>
{{#if DEFAULT}}
  <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" checked name="check[]">
{{else}}
  <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" name="check[]">
{{/if}}
</td>
```

to:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" {{#if DEFAULT}}checked{{/if}} name="check[]"></td>
```

Comment: Where is the code for the `DEFAULT` helper? Since it controls `checked`

Comment: It is an attribute of the trades object

Comment: <table> <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" checked name="check[]"></table>